Can a Catholic husband remarry when his wife has passed away after an annulment denial?
If a husband seeks an annulment and it is denied, but the wife dies after the annulment is denied, is he then free to remarry in the Catholic Church?

Can a Catholic husband remarry when his wife passed away after an annulment denial?
According to some Catholic traditions, a widower wears a wedding ring for a year before considering a remarriage.
The short answer is yes.

Remarriage of widows or widowers
The teaching of the Catholic Church is that a married couple commits themselves totally to one another until death. The vows they make to each other in the wedding rite are a commitment "til death do us part". After the death of one, the other is free to marry again or to remain single. Some choose to become priests or religious. This path was chosen by some even in the early Christian centuries by people such as Saint Marcella, Saint Paula, Saint Galla of Rome and Saint Olympias the Deaconess. - Marriage in the Catholic Church

The following may be helpful:

The Catholic Church, Divorce, and Annulment

